# What makes the AJAX call in this Laravel application fail?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I am working on a **[blogging application in Laravel 8](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0/pull/33/files)**.

The **ArticlesController** controller I have this method to display the single article and its *comments*:

```
class ArticlesController extends FrontendController {

    // More code

    public function show($slug) {
        // Single article
        $article = Article::firstWhere('slug', $slug);
        $old_article = Article::where('id', '<', $article->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
        $new_article = Article::where('id', '>', $article->id)->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->first();

        // Comments
        $commentsQuery = Comment::where(['article_id' => $article->id, 'approved' => 1])->orderBy('id', 'desc');
        $comments = $commentsQuery->paginate(10);
        $comments_count = $commentsQuery->count();

        return view('themes/' . $this->theme_directory . '/templates/single', 
            array_merge($this->data, [
                'categories' => $this->article_categories,
                'article' => $article,
                'old_article' => $old_article,
                'new_article' => $new_article,
                'comments' => $comments,
                'comments_count' => $comments_count,
                'tagline' => $article->title,
                ])
            );
    }

}
```

In the view I have this for the comments list:

```
<div id="commentsList">
  <ol class="commentlist {{ boolval($is_infinitescroll) ? 'infinite-scroll' : '' }}">
    @foreach ($comments as $comment)
    <li class="depth-1 comment">
      <div class="comment__avatar">
        <img class="avatar" src="{{ asset('images/avatars/' . $comment->user->avatar) }}" alt="" width="50" height="50">
      </div>
      <div class="comment__content">
        <div class="comment__info">
          <div class="comment__author">{{ $comment->user->first_name }} {{ $comment->user->last_name }}</div>
          <div class="comment__meta">
            <div class="comment__time">{{ date('jS M Y', strtotime($comment->created_at)) }}</div>
            <div class="comment__reply">
              <a class="comment-reply-link" href="#0">Reply</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="comment__text">
          <p>{{ $comment->body }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    @endforeach
  </ol>
  
  <div class="ajax-load text-center is-hidden">
    loading...
  </div>
</div>
```

The routes related to the article(s):

```
// Article routes
Route::get('/', [ArticlesController::class, 'index'])->name('homepage');
Route::get('/category/{category_id}', [ArticlesController::class, 'category'])->name('category');
Route::get('/author/{user_id}', [ArticlesController::class, 'author'])->name('author');
Route::get('/show/{slug}', [ArticlesController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
```

#### The goal

I want to replace the comments pagination with an "infinite scroll".

For this purpose, I have:

```
/* Infinite comments */
function infiniteComments() {
    var page = 1;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - $('.s-footer').height()) {
        page++;
        loadMoreData(page);
      }
    });
  }

  function loadMoreData(page){
    var base_url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
    $.ajax({
        url: `${base_url}?page=${page}`,
        type: "get",
        beforeSend: function() {
          $('.ajax-load').show();
        }
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        if (data.html == "") {
          $('.ajax-load').hide();
          return;
        }
        $('.ajax-load').hide();
        $(".infinite-scroll").append(data.html);
      })
      .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log('The server is not responding...');
      });
 }

 $(document).ready(function(){
    infiniteComments();
 });
```

#### The problem

While accessing `https://larablog.com/show/deserunt-qui-exercitationem?page=2` shows the comments on page 2 correctly, the Chrome console shows these *500 (Internal Server Error)* errors:

```
https://larablog.com/show/deserunt-qui-exercitationem?page=65 500 (Internal Server Error)
The server is not responding...

https://larablog.com/show/deserunt-qui-exercitationem?page=76 500 (Internal Server Error)
The server is not responding...
```

The error can be **tracked back** to this error message in ArticlesController, at line 70 - `$article = Article::firstWhere('slug', $slug)`:

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object.

This is strange because `$article = Article::firstWhere('slug', $slug)` **works fine** without Ajax.

#### Questions

1. What causes this bug?
2. What is the easiest fix?

Comment: What does your server's error log tell you about this? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: In addition to the above, what is the value of thrownError from your fail response handler method?

Comment: @Peppermintology `console.log(thrownError)` throws `Internal Server Error`.

Comment: And what's the root error? Try to enable a higher error reporting level in your app, or have  a look at the server's error log

Comment: @NicoHaase There is this error message in `ArticlesController`: `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`, but the log does not say on what line.

Comment: And what did you try to resolve the problem? Why not check whether 'Article::firstWhere` returns anything? Why not use a higher error reporting level?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir Can you post your routes code?

Comment: @sta See the GitHub repo (link in the first paragraph.)

Comment: `$article = Article::firstWhere('slug', $slug) works fine without Ajax.` can you share the url that works well without ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I have:

In `routes\web.php` this new route was added:

```
Route::post('/load_comments', [ArticlesController::class, 'get_comments_ajax'])->name('load_comments');
```

In the ArticlesController:

```
/**
 * AJAX Call for Loading extra comments
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function get_comments_ajax( Request $request ) {
    if ( ! $request->ajax() ) {
        // Redirect to Home Page or just BOMB OUT!
        exit();
    }

    $more_comments_to_display = TRUE;

    /** @todo - 5 - This should\could be a setting */

    $article_id  = $request->post( 'article_id' );
    $page_number = $request->post( 'page' );
    $offset      = $this->comments_per_page * $page_number;

    $data['comments'] = $this->get_commentQuery( $article_id, $this->comments_per_page, $offset )->get();
    $content          = '';
    if ( $data['comments']->count() ) {
        $content .= view('themes/' . $this->theme_directory . '/partials/comments-list',
            array_merge( $data, [
              'is_infinitescroll' => $this->is_infinitescroll
            ])
        );
    } else {
        $more_comments_to_display = FALSE;
    }
    echo json_encode( [ 'html' => $content, 'page' => $page_number, 'more_comments_to_display' => $more_comments_to_display, 'article_id' => $article_id ] );
    exit();
}

/**
 * get_commentQuery
 *
 * @param int $article_id
 * @param int $limit
 * @param int $offset
 *
 * @return object
 */
private function get_commentQuery( int $article_id, int $limit = 0, int $offset = 0 ): object {
    $commentQuery = Comment::where( [ 'article_id' => $article_id, 'approved' => 1 ] )->orderBy( 'id', $this->comments_orderby_direction );
    if ( $offset > 0 ) {
        $commentQuery = $commentQuery->offset( $offset );
    }
    if ( $limit > 0 ) {
        $commentQuery = $commentQuery->limit( $limit );
    }

    return $commentQuery;
}
```

I only load the Ajax script if there are more then 10 comments:

```
@if ($is_infinitescroll && $comments_count > $comments_per_page)
    @section('custom_js_files')
        <script src="{{ asset('themes/' . $theme_directory . '/js/infinite-comments.js') }}"></script>
    @endsection
@endif
```

##### The script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    let flagMoreCommentsToDisplay = true;
    let flagCommentsBlockNewRequest = false;
    let domInfiniteScroll = $(".infinite-scroll");

    infiniteComments();

    function infiniteComments() {
        let page = 0;
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if (flagCommentsBlockNewRequest === false) {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - $('.s-footer').height()) {
                    if (flagMoreCommentsToDisplay) {
                        flagCommentsBlockNewRequest = true;
                        page++;
                        loadMoreData(page);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function loadMoreData(page) {
        let base_url = window.location.origin
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + '/load_comments',
            type: 'POST', dataType: 'json',
            data: {'_token': token, 'page': page, 'article_id': article_id},
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('.ajax-load').show();
            }
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            $('.ajax-load').hide();
            let commentHtml = data.html;
            flagMoreCommentsToDisplay = data.more_comments_to_display;
            if (flagMoreCommentsToDisplay) {
                if (commentHtml !== '') {
                    domInfiniteScroll.append(commentHtml);
                }
            }
            flagCommentsBlockNewRequest = false;
        })
        .fail(function () {
            flagCommentsBlockNewRequest = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`firstWhere` returns the first record which meets the passed criteria, defaulting to `null`. So, your line of

```
$article = Article::firstWhere('slug', $slug);
```

will return the first article whose `slug` matches the `$slug`, or `null`, if no such record exists. Now, whenever you reference `$article->id`, you assume that `$article` is a proper `Article` and you wonder about the value of its `id`. This will yield the error you have experienced if there is no matching article.

So, it is wise to check for `empty($article)` just after `$article` was initialized and handle the edge-case when it is empty indeed.

Comment: How would _you_ do that and _where_ exactly in the code? And... does this solve the problem? :)

Comment: @RazvanZamfir I would (temporarily) do a `throw new Exception(json_encode($article));` just after your line of `$article = Article::firstWhere('slug', $slug);`, generating an error which would communicate what `$article` is. If it is `null`, then the error is that `firstWhere` returned with a `null`. This would narrow down your problem-space and strongly suggest that the solution is to either fix what slug is being passed (if that always needs to be valid), or handle the lack of matching slugs gracefully.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir as about the last question, this answer does not provide a ready-made solution for you yet, because at this point the culprit was not identified yet and it is unclear whether it is valid to expect your action to handle lacks of matches or, instead, the passing of the slug's value is the culprit, I need more contextual information in order to suggest a solution at this depth. So, this answer suggests how you can determine whether the (probable) issue is that the slug was unmatched and, as a general practice, this answer suggests defensively checking for the result of `firstWhere`.

Comment: The error can be tracked back to this error message in ArticlesController, at line 70 - `$article = Article::firstWhere('slug', $slug)`: `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object.`

Comment: We _do see the article_, so the variable `$article = Article::firstWhere('slug', $slug)` does not return null. What _we do not see_ is the comments, _stating from the 11th_. I think Laravel makes `empty($article)` unnecessary.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir is the `$commentsQuery = Comment::where(['article_id' => $article->id, 'approved' => 1])->orderBy('id', 'desc');` line throwing the exception?

Answer (score 1):

The error can be due to the following issues

1. Missing CSRF token ( Which seems not being sent using your AJAX )
2. Wrong Route or Conflict with another route
3. Route Param value not passing Correctly
4. Database Record missing or wrong field name.

Try the below example to debug to get your issue fixed

Always try to use the try-catch block to make Debugging easy for your self like the below example of your ArticlesController Code
Please use the below code and then check your Logs file under the directory

> storage/logs/laravel.log or file with laravel-28-08-2022.log

Then use that error log to find the actual cause of the 500 Internal Server Error

```
class ArticlesController extends FrontendController {

// More code

public function show($slug) {
    try{
    // Single article
    $article = Article::firstWhere('slug', $slug);
    $old_article = Article::where('id', '<', $article->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
    $new_article = Article::where('id', '>', $article->id)->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->first();

    // Comments
    $commentsQuery = Comment::where(['article_id' => $article->id, 'approved' => 1])->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    $comments = $commentsQuery->paginate(10);
    $comments_count = $commentsQuery->count();

    return view('themes/' . $this->theme_directory . '/templates/single', 
        array_merge($this->data, [
            'categories' => $this->article_categories,
            'article' => $article,
            'old_article' => $old_article,
            'new_article' => $new_article,
            'comments' => $comments,
    'comments_count' => $comments_count,
            'tagline' => $article->title,
            ])
        );
    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
       \Log::error("Error in file: ".$e->getFile()." , Error Message: ".$e->getMessage());
       return abort(500);
   }
}

}
```

Comment: There is no form, so what shall I o with the CSRF token? Where shall I add it?

Comment: did you try the try-catch block and got any errors? @RazvanZamfir

Comment: I did try it. No errors.

Comment: If you want, look in the **[repo](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0/pull/33/files)**.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir I can't see any try-catch block under your show function the ArticlesController.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir have a look at [PR-34](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0/pull/34)

Comment: I have this thing in the logs: `[2022-08-29 10:47:50] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `settings` limit 1) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `settings` limit 1) at E:\\wamp64\\www\\larablog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:712)`

Comment: Please post the complete log here. delete old file and hit request again to see what are the complete log details

Comment: @RazvanZamfir your database User credentials are not valid, please check your .env file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247645/discussion-between-razvan-zamfir-and-abdul-rehman).

Comment: First of all your JS is somehow strange.. This condition "if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) { .. " actually means it will fire these requests all the way until you're scrolling down. To be fired once when you are at the bottom it should be "if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) { ..". And I suppose after this blast of almost simultaneous requests, the DB could reject some, as you wrote it requested page 65 and 75.. and maybe this causes the error.

Comment: @Blum Correct. However, this is not related to the `500 (Internal Server Error)` error. The "deep cause" is `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir did you managed to resolve or not yet?